# Music won't play in .jar file

Tags: java

I check lot of topics about this problem here, but any of them could not solve my problem.
I have this method

```
String filepath = "resources/pacmanMusic.wav";
URL musicLocation = getClass().getResource(filepath);
//String musicPath = filepath.toString();

public void playMusic(String musicLocation) {
    if (play) {
        
        try {
            
            AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(musicLocation));
            File musicPath = new File(musicLocation);
            inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(musicPath);
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            System.out.println(musicLocation);
            clip.open(inputStream);
            clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
            clip.start();
            
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else {
        clip.stop();
    }
    System.out.println(play);
}
```

But I dont know, why music wont play in .jar if it plays in eclipse. From others "topics" I got always errors like file is null or something like that.
This is how I call the method above `playMusic(filepath);`
What I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: Are you getting an exception when you run your code?

Comment: no, everything run fine

Comment: If you wan't to run mp3 from disk, you should specify absolute path to that file. For now you can only play files from `resources/` folder of your jar file

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```java
InputStream fileInputStream = YourAwesomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("yourFile.mp3");
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(fileInputStream);
```

From what I see, your `.mp3` should be saved in the resources folder. When creating a jar the file paths are translated into "jar paths" and are not so well handled. That's why using an `InputStream` would be a good idea.